# Android, Picasso, Firebase Storage - Retrieve Image, Nothing is being showed on ImageView

Tags: android, image, firebase, storage, picasso

I already tried using Glide.with(opDetails.this).using(new FirebaseImageLoader()).load(uri).into(imgPhoto1);    but had some problems with .using(). 
I am now trying to use picasso. Althougt the compiler shows no error, no image is displayed to the ImageView and i cant understand why.

```
    storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    storageRef = storage.getReference();

    storageRef.child("images/4736af35-608d-4b97-95ba-029ef471c5eb.png").getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
            Picasso.with(opDetails.this).load(uri).into(imgPhoto1);

        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {

        }
    });
}
```

Update:

[Firebase Storage Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0u2W.png)

[Storage Rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNDTh.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should use error listener and see what error is displayed-

Picasso.with(opDetails.this).load(uri).into(imgPhoto1, new Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess()
                    {
                    }
                    public void onError()
                    {
                    }
                });

Also add a log in addOnFailureListener to see if uri is properly fetched from database.

Comment: it says  com.google.storage.StorageException: Object does not exist at location

Comment: This means there might be some problem with storing the images. Send the storage folder and its structure @NunoLeal

Comment: question updated @Raj

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
storageRef.child("images/4736af35-608d-4b97-95ba-029ef471c5eb").getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener....
```

Comment: After removing the .png what exception are you getting in addOnFailureListener() @NunoLeal ?

Comment: None it suddenly moves to the previous activity without showing the reason @Raj

Comment: already tried using: storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://... .appspot.com/"); but stills the same @Raj